# Live helper chat - Your IP is not allowed to perform updates

Tags: php, javascript, chat, cpanel

Estou tentando configurar o *script* do [Live Helper Chat](https://livehelperchat.com/) para atualizar automaticamente, mas não estou conseguindo. Já pedi ajuda no [forum](https://forum.livehelperchat.com/viewtopic.php?pid=12949) deles, mas são sempre incompletas as respostas.

As instruções que existem são estas: https://livehelperchat.com/how-to-automate-live-helper-chat-updates-338a.html

Tudo o que faço aparece esta mensagem: **Your IP is not allowed to perform updates**

Até agora não sei como autorizar meu *IP*. Alguém sabe como fazer essa autorização?

Answer (score 0):

Há a possibilidade do *auto update* está instável, já que não faz tanto tempo assim que foi adicionado, ou ser um recurso *"Premium"* com a necessidade de liberação (que acho pouco provável), todavia, vou te passar instruções para a atualização manual.

Sinto não ser exatamente o que procuras, porém irá quebrar o galho até facilitarem/corrigirem esse erro.

---

**1.** Baixe a versão do Chat.

---

**2.** Logue no painel administrativo, vá até *Configurações* **>** Aba *Sistema* **>* clique na 2ª opção, *Informações de atualização*.

Perceba que na tela que exibiu, mostra a versão atual e a mais recente; do lado direito, alguns campos ficaram em vermelho, isso significa que há recursos ausentes, que estão na versão mais recente. Clique em *Atualizar banco de dados*.

Após isso você receberá a seguinte mensagem de cor verde:

> Seu banco de dados não necessita de nenhuma atualização

Isso significa que todas as atualizações referente ao *DB* foram aplicadas.

> Obs.: Usuários com conta de Operadores precisarão usar a opção '*Limpar cache*' para evitar conflitos. O *link Limpar Cache* pode ser visto na página de configuração do sistema.

---

**3.** Faça o Logout.

Usando a nova versão que você baixou, substitua as seguintes pastas:
doc, ezcomponents, lib, modules, pos, translations e design.

---

**4.** Vá em *settings* e abra o arquivo *settings.ini.php*, mude para `false` as seguintes funções:

```
'templatecache' => false,
'templatecompile' => false,
'modulecompile' => false,
```

---

**5.** Salve, e faça o *login*, vá até configurações e clique em *limpar cache*.

Agora volte no arquivo *settings.ini.php* e habilite o *cache*:

```
'templatecache' => true,
'templatecompile' => true,
'modulecompile' => true,
```

---

Isso deve te ajudar por hora, sinto o tutorial um pouquinho longo, espero realmente ter lhe ajudado, pelo menos até que essa instabilidade seja sanada.